# custom Alexa skill ExampleSkillIntentHandler being properly triggered but getting "Sorry, I had trouble doing what you asked. Please try again."

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit

I'm building an Alexa custom skill. I tried the "Hello World" example and it worked just fine. However, when coding my own skill (using that stub -practically unmodified, except for the names and strings) I get a "Sorry, I had trouble doing what you asked. Please try again." message when saying anything.
For example: 
Me: my skill name

Simulator: Welcome to my skill name, you can say help or exampleSkill. Which would you like to try?

Me: example Skill  //(Properly configured in the Intents)

Simulator: "Sorry, I had trouble doing what you asked. Please try again."

The json request exactly the same as the HelloWorld example, but the response is not. 
Even if I type "dfjsgdsf" it will send the correct json request (exampleSkill) but will trigger the same CatchAllExceptionHandler.

I'd appreciate your thoughts on this. I'm sure it's a pretty silly thing I'm missing. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

For me it sounds you only adapted the backend.
But you also need to adapt and build the model in the alexa developer console.
So start from the beginning -> what you are saying to get the intent fired. Is is it in the list of utterances for that intent (HelloWorldIntent?)?

This is what I saw in the example:
https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-hello-world/blob/master/models/en-US.json
So if you try your "dfjsgdsf" -> this is not initially not configured in the model.